# Continuous Functions - Topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'd like to prove the following.

> A function $f:X \to Y$ is continuous if whenever $A$ is closed in $Y$,
>   $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $X$.

**Proof.** By definition, a function is continuous if the inverse image of every open set is open. Suppose that $A\in Y$ is closed. Then, $Y-A$ is open, so $f^{-1}(Y-A)$ is open.

$f^{-1}(Y-A) = X - f^{-1}(A)$ is open. So $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed.

Is this correct?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Okay. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like your proof is in the wrong direction. You have proved that if $f$ is continuous, then whenever $A$ is closed $f^{-1}(A)$ is also closed.

Comment: @DanShved No! it's the correct direction. Closeness $\implies$ Continuity

Comment: The last phrase in your proof is "thus $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed". Looks like "closeness" is on the right hand side of the arrow.

Comment: @saadtaame, what you wrote  " Then, $Y-A$ is open, so $f^{-1}(Y-A)$ is open" wrongly assumes that $\,f\,$ is already continuous, which is what you want to prove.

Comment: @DonAntonio That assumption is true by definition (a function is continuous if the inverse image of an open set is open).

Comment: But you want to prove that $\,f\,$ is continuous if the inverse image of every closed set is closed, @saadtaame! It is **continuity** of $\,f\,$ that you want to prove, so you can **not** assume it.

Comment: @DonAntonio We already have a theorem (or definition) that uses open sets, why can't we use it? It's a given.

Comment: Because you don't know that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Ah now I see my mistake. I'll try to fix it. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

You cannot assume what you want to prove: suppose that whenever $\,A\subset Y\,$ is closed then also $\,f^{-1}(A)\subset X\,$ is closed.

Let $\,U\subset Y\,$ be open $\;\implies Y\setminus U\;$ is closed, so by asumption $\,f^{-1}\left(Y\setminus U\right)\;$ is closed in $\;X\;$  and thus $\;X\setminus f^{-1}(Y\setminus U)\;$ is open.

But $\,X\setminus f^{-1}(Y\setminus U)\subset f^{-1}(U)\;$  since:

$$z\in X\setminus f^{-1}(Y\setminus U)\implies z\notin f^{-1}(Y\setminus U)\implies f(z)\notin Y\setminus U\implies$$

$$f(z)\in U$$

Deduce now that in fact $\,f^{-1}(U)\;$ is open and thus $\,f\,$ fulfills the usual definition of continuity, i.e. $\,f\,$ is continuous.

Comment: I know that a set is closed is it's complement is open. It works in the other direction as well?

Comment: Yes, it is an iff thing: a set is open iff its complement is closed.

Comment: Okay, I'll use your proof (excluding the inclusion part). So we know that $X-f^{-1}(Y-U)$ is open. But $$X-f^{-1}(Y-U)=X-(X-f^{-1}(U))=f^{-1}(U)$$. Thus $f^{-1}(U)$ is open proving that $f$ is continuous by the usual definition. Right?

Comment: Hmmm...can you prove your first equality? If so then yes: you're done.